# C#, EF 5.0, C# server pagination, count total slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I make api with server pagination.
How to optimize server pagination? It is possible to apply another approach. For each request, I count the total number of items to correctly display the number of pages. Count is slow...

```
public static async Task<Tuple<List<T>, int>> GetFilteredAndTotal<T>(this IQueryable<T> enumerator, FilterContainer filter)
    {
        if (filter == null)
        {
            int c = await enumerator.CountAsync();
            return new Tuple<List<T>, int>(await enumerator.ToListAsync(), c);
        }
        if (filter.Where != null)
        {
            enumerator = enumerator.Where(filter.Where);
        }

        var count = enumerator.LongCount();
        if (filter.OrderBy != null)
        {
            enumerator = enumerator.OrderBy(filter.OrderBy);
        }
        if (filter.Take != -1)
        {
            enumerator = enumerator.Skip(filter.Skip).Take(filter.Take);
        }
        // var test12 = enumerator.ToList();

        return new Tuple<List<T>, int>(await enumerator.ToListAsync(), (int)count);
    }
```

Comment: That won't actually impact total speed but it seems like you've missed `LongCountAsync` now you are using sync version of it.

Comment: @Neistow given ```LongCount``` is being called from an ```IQueryable``` it will impact speed as it's making a call to the DB server. However, it is a necessary action so don't think there's much that can be done about it. Also, yes the async version should be used.

Comment: @YungDeiza Ofc it will impact speed since it will trigger db query. What I mean is `async` version should be used since calling `sync` version will keep thread busy, but that's beyond the scope of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with counts over large sets, performance will really take a hit in more dynamic search scenarios because you won't be leveraging indexes in all search scenarios. One option I use to address this is to perform more pagination oriented counts. This means interacting with your pagination via PageNumber and PageSize rather than a Skip and Count.

For example, if your pagination control displays 10 pages and something like a ">" to get to 11-20 etc. and a page size of 50, then I will do an initial count using the following formula:

```
int maxItems = ((pageNumber-1)/10 + 1) * 10 * pageSize + 1;
```

What this means is if page number is 1-10 we want to select a max of 501 items. If we are on page 11 then we want 1001, and so on. We only want to load enough data for up to the last visible page, plus 1 record to determine if there is at least 1 more page beyond that.

Now when you go to load your data, you limit the results to maxItems. So for instance when loading the paged data for page 1 by default:

```
var itemCount = enumerator.Take(maxItems).Count();
var items = await enumerator.Skip((pageNumber-1)*pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

From there you could return a tuple of your results, the count, and whether there are more items:

```
return new Tuple<List<T>, int, bool>(items, itemCount, itemCount == maxItems);
```

Note that the maxItems is only needed in order to get the count.

Then in your UI your pagination would get say 501 items back and could display the 10 pages plus the ">" because there would technically be 11 pages returned. You can check the "more items" Boolean to alter how you return a row count, so if True then display something like (itemCount -1 ) + "+ items" for "500+ items". If < 501 items were returned you display the actual # of items and the <= 10 pages of results as per normal.

When the user triggers going to the 11th page, the algorithm now loads 1001 items and can display page 11, and up to page 20, again possibly displaying "1000+" items if 1001 items were loaded. As they navigate past the last page of results it automatically loads more for the next 10 pages. If your pagination control "walks" (I.e. adjusts so that on page 8 it shows something like pages 4-14 rather than staying on 1-10 until page 11) then you would need a bit more logic to ensure that the range + 1 is always reflecting 1 more item than the max available page.

The premise of this is that users are typically only interested in the first few pages of data, so keep that typical scenario as fast and relevant as possible. It's rare that they would step through page by page looking for a result rather than refining their search to narrow down the # of results to look through.  You can display the page count as a hyperlink or provide an action that can wait for a real, accurate count if the users are more interested in getting the actual # of matching items. The load will get slower the more complete sets of pages the user tries to load, and you can consider locking it down to the first 20 or 50 pages of results before requiring users to narrow down their search criteria. This is more to avoid giving users a means to bog down the web servers with "silly" requests.

The limitation of this approach is that you cannot provide a >| / >> to go to last page navigation option for the pagination control, since that would require knowing the accurate count of items. Again, this is weighing up the value and utility of such an action, vs. doing the same thing via reversing the sort order.